# google closure and MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild

looking to implement google closure with msbuild.
i found a few solutions but struggling to get it working.
any suggestions on how i can read multiple js files in and create .min versions during build?

thanks

EDIT: with the answer from below i was able to make some alterations with a view to fully implement what was recommended but in a simple form here is what i've wrote:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <JSMin Include="$(OutputPath)Scripts\*.js"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Inputs="@(JSMin)" Outputs="@(JSMin ->'%(Directory)%(Filename).min%(Extension)')">
    <Exec Command="java -jar C:\temp\compiler.jar --js %(JSMin.Identity) --js_output_file C:\temp\%(JSMin.Filename).min.js"/>
  </Target>
```

the output path will be changed to a dynamic path later on.

many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't looked at Google Closure, but you can run any command through the [`<Exec>` task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx):

```
<Project DefaultTargets="build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="build">
        <Exec Command="echo Hello world"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

**Edit:** To run a command over a set of files:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <JSMin Include="jquery.js"/>
    <JSMin Include="somethingelse.js"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="build" Inputs="@(JSMin)" Outputs="@(JSMin->'%(Directory)%(Filename).min%(Extension)')">
    <Exec Command="java -jar C:\temp\compiler.jar --js %(JSMin.Identity) --js_output_file %(JSMin.Directory)%(JSMin.Filename).min%(JSMin.Extension)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: yeah that works fine.  but i need to iterate over a directory of scripts and create the min folder. for example, a single compression works: <Exec Command="java -jar C:\temp\compiler.jar --js C:\temp\jquery.color.js --js_output_file C:\temp\jquery.color.min.js"></Exec>

Comment: @nologo, see my edit. The MSDN documentation on MSBuild is useful. Item groups are explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx

Comment: In my case I was getting a build error "exited with code 9009". This was due a path with spaces. Quotation with &quot; removed that error. Thanks.